# Remix fetcher without its Form?

Tags: remix.run

I have a main `fetcher.Form` on my page for the main actions of the page. I also need to track certain events on the page, and I will do this by calling a separate resource action when the events happen. I was using another `fetcher.Form` to call this action, but I am not allowed to nest a form within another form (`validateDOMNesting` errors).

```
const { Form, submit } = useFetcher()

function reportRecentProductsViewed(products: ViewedProduct[]) {
  submit(
    { products: JSON.stringify(products) },
    {
      method: 'post',
      action: '/actions/track-products-viewed',
    }
  )
}

<Form>
  <ViewedProductsProvider reportRecentProductsViewed={reportRecentProductsViewed}>
    <Outlet/> {/* other "main" form is in the outlet */}
  </ViewedProductsProvider>
</Form>
```

I tried just removing the `<Form>` tags, and `fetcher.submit` still works! I just want to make sure -- is this correct?? Am I okay to use `fetcher.submit` without a `<fetcher.Form>`?

Bonus question: looks like there's also `useSubmit`, which I imagine could also be used without a form, if `useFetcher` can be used without a form. Is there any reason to prefer `useSubmit` over `useFetcher`? I'm not using any of the other returns from `useFetcher`, but am I costing anything extra to use it anyway?

**UPDATE:** But wait! I tried using `const submit = useSubmit()` in place of `const { submit } = useFetcher()` and they are decidedly not the same. When I use `useSubmit`, calling `submit` (with the same config with `post`) navigates to the action route! Which is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `<fetcher.Form>` is a declarative way to use `fetcher` hooks.

And `useSubmit` is an imperative way to use the `<Form>` component.

Remember that Forms are navigations, whereas fetchers and fetcher.Forms are not.

I typically try the declarative approach first. The components and hooks both call the same code, so there isn't really a difference between how you use them.

Also, although HTML prevents you from nesting `<form>`, you can have buttons that reference another form by `id`.

```html
<form method="post">
  <input .../> 
  <input .../>
  <!-- standard submit button -->
  <button>Submit</button>
  <button form="delete-form">Delete</button>
</form>
<!-- sibling form that will be submitted when clicking delete button -->
<form id="delete-form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="intent" value="delete" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" />
</form>
```

Here's a Remix example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-gwmg8d?file=app%2Froutes%2F_index.tsx

Comment: "And useSubmit is an imperative way to use the <Form> component" but can it be used *without* the Form component? I think this is what you're saying but not 100% clear

Comment: No, it doesn't _require_ a `Form`, but it is typically used with one. For example, you can submit JSON data if you want: `submit({ "name": "kiliman"}, {method:"post"})`. The main thing to know is that `useSubmit()` will cause a navigation.

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-submit